# My laptop screen won't work with any version of Linux

Tags: drivers, display, laptop, intel, proprietary-drivers

Ok, so I'm using an Asus Zenbook UX431FA, which uses the Intel UHD 620 driver for its graphics processing.
I want to dual boot a Linux distro, so that I can utilise the full power of the CPU and RAM.  So far I've tried Ubuntu, Kali, and Parrot OS.  Every single one of them has the same problem: the laptop screen goes blank and won't work with the Linux OS.

I've got an extended monitor working on an HDMI cable, and this displays everything fine... albeit I can't access the main screen of the linux distro where all the fun stuff happens.

How, oh how, can I get the monitor to work with Linux?

I've tried using nomodeset in GRUB, etc. and even playing with the edid settings - which I only got so far with Parrot OS because the EDID file didn't seem to be where it should.

Can anyone help me?  I would really love to say "Adios Amigos" to my Microsoft Windows, or at least just spend most of my time in a Linux Distro and only use Windows when I absolutely have to.

Comment: Does your laptop screen work if you don't have the HDMI screen attached? If you _boot_ without the HDMI screen attached?

Comment: No.  I just followed the instructions in the answer ... well ... kind of - I couldn't use tty1 on the laptop screen but I could get to the terminal so I upgraded the kernel from backports.  Now the laptop screen works but not the extension screen ... at least I can use the features of the Linux machine tho

Comment: Just booted without the HDMI attached... it seems updating the kernel fixed the laptop screen but the HDMI port (external monitor port) is no longer recognized by the system.

Answer (score 2):

Try to switch to tty1 with Ctrl+Alt+F1 when you are using your laptop screen. Log in and run `lshw -c display`, if your screen is marked as `UNCLAIMED` it is not correctly recognized by the kernel and you need to install a more recent version of the kernel, for example from backports. You can also see the messages in `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`.